# SugarCRM Smarty Code in Listviewdefs

Tags: php, smarty, sugarcrm

I'm trying to use Smarty PHP for custom functionality in the ListView (custom/modules/Leads/metadata/listviewdefs.php) of SugarCRM (6.5.3).

This works fine:

```
'customCode' => '{$LD_ASSUMED_SUGAR_ACCOUNT_ID_C}',
```

And so does this:

```
'customCode' => '{$ACCOUNT_NAME}',
```

However this just outputs the code (brackets and all) in the List (but with Account name substituted for the correct value):

```
'customCode' => '{if $LD_ASSUMED_SUGAR_ACCOUNT_ID_C}{$ACCOUNT_NAME}{/if}',
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve the same result you are looking for in ListView like you can in EditView & DetailView. One way to go about this is to add a non-db field to Leads vardefs and use a logic hook to handle conditional formatting.

**Create a new vardef:**

/custom/Extension/modules/Cases/Ext/Vardefs/my_listview_value_c.php

```
<?php
    $dictionary['Lead']['fields']['my_listview_value_c'] = array(
      'name' => 'my_listview_value_c',
      'vname' => 'LBL_MY_LISTVIEW_VALUE_C',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'len' => '255',
      'source' => 'non-db',
    );
?>
```

**Create the logic hook:**

/custom/modules/Leads/ListViewLogicHook.php

```
<?php
class ListViewLogicHook {

    public function getListValue(&$bean, $event, $arguments) {
        if ($bean->ld_assumed_sugar_account_id_c) {
            $bean->my_listview_value_c = $bean->account_name;
        } else {
            // Whatever you'd like
        }
    }
}
```

**Add the logic hook entry:**

```
// position, file, function
$hook_array['process_record'] = Array();
$hook_array['process_record'][] = Array(1, 'Conditional formatting in a listview column', 'custom/modules/Leads/ListViewLogicHook.php','ListViewLogicHook','getListValue');
```

**Finally, in your listviewdefs add the new column:**

```
'MY_LISTVIEW_VALUE_C' => 
    array (
        'width' => '10%',
        'label' => 'LBL_MY_LISTVIEW_VALUE_C',
        'default' => true,
 ),
```

Hope that helps.